# Images on XAML not getting 'anti-aliased' after reloading

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm building an Windows 10 weather app, and I'm facing a really strange behaviour with images. I have an Image control to show the user the current weather (pictures below). The first time the image is loaded, it's fine, but when I change the image (updating the weather), the image has a bad quality, just like an anti-aliasing had not been applied.

The image on the first load:

[image: Image First Load]

The image when it's reloaded:

[image]

The code that i'm using to set the Source to the image control (both on the first load and reload):

```
WeatherImageControl.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri($"ms-appx:///Assets/Weather/{weatherType}.png", UriKind.Absolute));
```

The XAML control is as simple as can be, and it's contained in a StackPanel:

```
<Image Name="WeatherImageControl" />
```

This problem only occurs when the same image is being reloaded, so I imagine that it may be some caching issue.